# Comparing 2 dates (failing if one of the dates is in following year)

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below works fine if the 2 dates are within the same year, but seems to break if the end date is in the following year. Could anyone point me in the right direction as to why?

Both vars are date pickers in the format DD/MM/YYYY.

Thanks in advance.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#start").change(  function() {   
        var startDate = $('#start').val().replace('/','');
        var endDate = $('#due').val().replace('/','');
        if(startDate > endDate){
           $("#due").val($(this).val());
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "break"? Any exceptions?

Comment: Unexpected results are probably coming from comparing those strings in that way. Consider converting them to a Date type before comparing them.

Comment: also, 2012 is > than 2011 so your if statement should fail if the date is the following year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comparison will only work if the dates are in format YYYY-MM-DD. If `val()` is a string (in the format DD/MM/YYYY), you can do:

```
var startDate = $('#start').val().split('/').reverse().join('-');
var endDate = $('#due').val().split('/').reverse().join('-');
```

Then you can compare them.

Answer (score 1):

if your startdate is like 10/12/2012 and your enddate is the 10/01/2013 take a look at your code and what it generates:

```
"10/12/2012" -> "10122012”
"10/01/2013" -> "10012013"
```

what you do is comparing 2 strings against each other, and at the third position the first string is bigger than the second.

you should us [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to compare dates.

if you want it easier, take a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

Like  Patrick James McDougle said, it's probably not a good idea to compare dates by strings. Try the [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object, like this:

```
$("#start").change(  function() {   
     var startDate = new Date($('#start').val());
     var endDate = new Date($('#due').val());
     if (startDate > endDate){
          $("#due").val($(this).val());
     }
});
```

Comment: I did try this but then it didn't work at all... maybe something to do with the date picker perhaps? The only solution was to use Augusto's, although I understand it's better to use a date object now.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing, for example, 1232013 (1/23/2013) with 12232012 (12/23/2012). The latter is a larger numeric value, but it is an earlier date.

Comment: I see - I was thinking val() cast the value. Looked it up just now and saw my mistake.